# iPhone SDK: How do I create an overlay drop-down menu?

Tags: iphone, uiview, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a UIViewController containing its UIView which occupies the available screen (inbetween the tabbar and nav bar).

I'd now like to add a simple toolbar which is situated at the top of the UIView which will contain some buttons. One of the buttons should display a drop down menu which is displayed as an overlay over the UIView. I'd quite like this menu to be a UITable as it could contain many items.

The problem I'm having is I can't see the best way to go about this. I'm wondering whether there's a simple strategy.

Here's an example of the type of feature I'm looking for...

Menu hidden: http://www.flickr.com/photos/peterevers/3147678219/in/photostream/
Menu displayed: http://www.flickr.com/photos/peterevers/3148550320/

I expect the above example is emulated in UIWebView using HTML/CSS. Is there a "proper" way?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a `UIView`, actually I create a new Status Bar, custom Color, graphics, and a clock on it, the menu `UIButton` has this function called, but make sure also in your H to add the button and the `UIView` and attach it to the newly created `UIView` in IB....  `IBOutlet UIView *nameofMenuUIView;`

```
[self addSubview:nameofMenuUIView];
```

or you could do

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransistion:READBELOW forView:self cache:YES];
[self addSubview:nameofMenuUIView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

**READ BELOW:** this READBELOW text above can be changed to 103 104 110 or even  page curl up/down etc.... look for Animating UIView's their is about 6 animations you can use, however 3 of them are dedicated to the camera roll, so pointless for a menu...

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly use the buttons that you want in your menu to show and hide a UITableView.  There is no need for a WebView, I think you are already on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in support for this.  It seems straightforward to implement - make sure the table view is beneath the header, then move it and the content view down when you want to show it.  Was there a particular part you were stuck with?

Another option is to use a third-party library such as [HGKOptionPanel](https://github.com/Hegaka/HGKOptionPanel) or [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover).